# Why is "context.Apify" undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, apify

I'm trying to learn how to use request in Apify Web-Scraper Actor, I don't understand how it works.

I first did this with Postman, I did get the result I wanted, now I want to do the same on Apify.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {...
    const request = new context.Apify.Request({
        url:...
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json' },
        method: 'POST',
        payload:{...}
    })
}
```

I would like to get a Json files corresponding to this request. Instead I get an error : "Cannot read property 'Request' of undefined"

Comment: Thanks for updating the code to show that it was running in `pageFunction`

Comment: Why do you need the `Apify.Request` constructor? You almost never need to create the instance of `Request` yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.Apify` is only available in [Puppeteer Scraper](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper), not in Web Scraper. Web Scraper is just a simple in-browser interface so porting all Apify functions into the browser would be almost impossible.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much I'll use the Puppeteer Scraper then

Comment: Can you please mark this as a correct answer? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may not have imported the Apify library using by installing it with npm (`npm install apify`) and then using `const Apify = require('apify');`

There is example at the bottom of [this page](https://sdk.apify.com/) under "Try It Out"

Comment: I get this error :
Error: Compilation of pageFunction failed.
Unexpected identifier
npm install apify
^^^^^^^

Comment: I'm not sure what that means... are you entering `npm install apify` into your file?  It should be ran in terminal in the local project to install the node package.

Comment: Yes i did enter "npm install apify" directly in my code, what do you mean by "ran in terminal" ?

Comment: Guys, Maxime is talking about [Web Scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper) actor on Apify platform. You cannot install anything there. To install libraries, you need to create a new custom actor or port them into the browser.

Comment: In the pageFunction, you are in browser context so you can use full Chrome browser API but not Node.js.